# 2xbelongs_to, A unique for B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
def User
  has_many :conversation_participants
end

def Conversation
  has_many :conversation_participants
end

def ConversationParticipant
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd like to add validation to ConversationParticipant so that only one record of the same user (user_id) for one conversation (conversation_id) can exist. So this would be invalid:

```
id  user_id  conversation_id
1   1        1
2   2        1
3   1        1 # <-- invalid
4   3        1
```

Any keywords that describe this problem (for future Googlin') are appreciated.

EDIT: Some code

```
c = Conversation.first
c.conversation_participants.build(:user => User.first)
c.save # => true

c.conversation_participants.build(:user => User.first)
c.save # => false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:conversation_id]

Or sexy validations:

> validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:conversation_id]}

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a :uniq into has_many:

```
def User
  has_many :conversation_participants, :uniq => true
end

def Conversation
  has_many :conversation_participants, :uniq => true
end

def ConversationParticipant
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

[RoR Associations (uniqueness constraint is about 3/4 of the way down).](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: "In the above case there are still two readings. However person.posts shows only one post because the collection loads only unique records." I don't know if it does prevent a record that does not fill the uniqueness requirement I have as I haven't tried it (because Andy's was perfect for me.)

Comment: Furthermore I believe that this validation would belong in the ConversationParticipant model, but I suppose that's just a personal preference. :)